# No indentation in footnote with kableExtra::kbl for latex output

Tags: r, kableextra

I am trying to remove the indention in the footnote section of a table created with kableExtra. I am assuming that the indention comes from the `\item` function that stands before the note begins (see latex output). Could anybody help to remove this indention resp. the `\item` prefix from the note?

```
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)

data(mtcars)
tab_data <- mtcars[1:5, 1:3]

cat(
  kbl(
    x = tab_data,
    format = "latex",
    booktabs = TRUE,
  ) %>%
    kable_styling(full_width = FALSE) %>%
    footnote(
      general = "Here is a note of the table. It is very long and I would want to remove this ugly indention on the left side of the table notes. ",
      general_title = "",
      threeparttable = TRUE
    )
)
```

Here the latex output:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}[t]{lrrr}
\toprule
  & mpg & cyl & disp\\
\midrule
Mazda RX4 & 21.0 & 6 & 160\\
Mazda RX4 Wag & 21.0 & 6 & 160\\
Datsun 710 & 22.8 & 4 & 108\\
Hornet 4 Drive & 21.4 & 6 & 258\\
Hornet Sportabout & 18.7 & 8 & 360\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item Here is a note of the table. It is very long and I would want to remove this ugly indention on the left side of the table notes. 
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

And a print sreen of the PDF and with the indention:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `footnote_as_chunk = T`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)

data(mtcars)
tab_data <- mtcars[1:5, 1:3]

kbl(
    x = tab_data,
    format = "latex",
    booktabs = TRUE,
  ) %>%
    kable_styling(full_width = FALSE) %>%
    footnote(
      general = "Here is a note of the table. It is very long and I would want to remove this ugly indention on the left side of the table notes. ",
      general_title = "",
      threeparttable = TRUE,
      footnote_as_chunk = T
    )
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Almost perfect! There is still a small indention on the first line. I think it is because in the latex output the footnote is still marked as `\item`. But I think there is no way around this? Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind changing packages, you could use huxtable. You can then customize padding, borders etc. as you prefer:

```r
library(huxtable)
tab_data <- cbind(model = rownames(tab_data), tab_data)
huxtable(tab_data) |> 
      set_width(0.5) |> 
      theme_article() |>
      add_footnote("Here is a note of the table. It is very long and I would want to remove this ugly indention on the left side of the table notes. ") |> 
      theme_
      set_left_padding(everywhere, 1, 0.1) # change 0.1 to whatever you prefer
      quick_pdf()
```

[image: huxtable PDF output]

One thing to be aware of: this simply adds a cell to the bottom of the table. It doesn't use a TeX footnote or tablenote.

Comment: Uh, nice suggestion! I definitely have to take a look into `huxtable`. I won't accept your post as an answer because the answer of bttomio suits more the posted question.